# HTTP Requests from SSL Secured(HTTPS) Domain Failing

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ssl, https, microservices

I have Cloudflare SSL secured Domain. My Angular 14 Frontend is deployed on DigitalOcean Droplet A. I am able to open my website homepage with https://my-domain. I have a number of SpringBoot Microservices deployed on DigitalOcean Droplet B. Please note that all my microservices are deployed with the help of Docker containers. I have Eureka Discovery Service and API Gateway also deployed on droplet B. I am able to access all the services from Postman as http reqeusts which means all my services including my API Gateway, Eureka Discovery Service is working fine. The issue is when I am sending the same requests from my domain, I am getting failed request. I am sure it is because my frontend which is SSL secured is sending http request to backend. I am using Load Balancing in my Gateway. My Gateway is accessible on droplet via droplet-ip:8082 port. This is the first time I am implementing website with SSL and https. How can I resolve this issue? My website was working fine before I implemented SSL.

I am totally new to this type of implementation. I am really not sure where to start exploring this issue as answers on several forums, although talk about similar issue, don't really help solve this kind of issue.